# Is there a way to mimic an interface/contract for shared methods in a class for use by generics?

Tags: vb.net

So I implemented my own form of Enum static classes so I can associate strings to enumeration values.  One of the shared functions in each enum class, `GetValue`, is used to quickly look up the string value from an internal array via the offset.  While all of the enum classes implement the same exact function, the data types of their parameters differ, specific to the enums in each class.

So I come to a point where I want to create a generic class that can use any of the enums by passing it as a generic type parameter.  But I cannot find a way to constrain type `T` in such a way to be able to call each enum's `GetValue` function.  This is where an interface would come in handy, but VB.NET forbids interfaces for shared methods.

I have a base class that I could constrain to, but the base class doesn't implement the `GetValue` method, and I can't define a generic version of it, because I need to rely on shared properties of each child class in order for `GetValue` to do its thing.

Is there another way to tackle this?

**EDIT:**
Here's what an example enum class looks like.  The parent, `EBase` is nothing special, just hosting common `Name`, `Value`, and `Type` properties, plus two shared operators, `op_Equality` and `op_Inequality`.  Imagine using a couple of these enum classes with a generic method (or class) and needing to access the `GetValue` member via the generic type parameter `T`.

```
Friend NotInheritable Class EExample
    Inherits EBase

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub


    Friend Shared Function GetValue(ByVal Name As String) As Enums
        Return Enums(Array.IndexOf(_Names, Name))
    End Function


    'Num of Enums defined.
    Friend Shared ReadOnly MaxEnums As Int32 = 5

    'String literals.
    Private Shared ReadOnly _Names As String() = New String() _
        {"one_adam", "two_boy", "three_charles", "four_david", "five_edward"}

    'Enums.
    Friend Shared ReadOnly OneA As New Enums(_Names(0), 0)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly TwoB As New Enums(_Names(1), 1)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly ThreeC As New Enums(_Names(2), 2)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly FourD As New Enums(_Names(3), 3)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly FiveE As New Enums(_Names(4), 4)


    'Enum Values Array.
    Friend Shared ReadOnly Values As Enums() = New Enums() _
        {OneA, TwoB, ThreeC, FourD, FiveE}


    Friend NotInheritable Class Enums
        Inherits EBase

        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        Friend Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Value As Int32)
            MyBase.Name = Name
            MyBase.Value = Value
            MyBase.Type = GetType(Enums)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

**EDIT2:**
Here's how the things are used:

```
Dim Foo As EExample.Enums
Foo = EExample.TwoB
Debug.Print(Foo.Name)
```

will print `two_boy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this as a solution:

```
Friend NotInheritable Class EExample
    Inherits EBase

    Protected Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function BuildValues() As EBase.Enums()
        Return New Enums() _
        { _
            Build(Of EExample)("one_adam", 0), _
            Build(Of EExample)("two_boy", 1), _
            Build(Of EExample)("three_charles", 2), _
            Build(Of EExample)("four_david", 3), _
            Build(Of EExample)("five_edward", 4) _
        }
    End Function

    Private Shared _instance As EExample = New EExample()

    Friend Shared ReadOnly OneA As Enums = _instance.Values(0)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly TwoB As Enums = _instance.Values(1)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly ThreeC As Enums = _instance.Values(2)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly FourD As Enums = _instance.Values(3)
    Friend Shared ReadOnly FiveE As Enums = _instance.Values(4)

End Class
```

`EBase` then looks like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class EBase

    Protected MustOverride Function BuildValues() As Enums()

    Private _values As EBase.Enums()

    Friend ReadOnly Property Values() As EBase.Enums()
        Get
            If _values Is Nothing Then
                _values = Me.BuildValues()
            End If
            Return _values
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend ReadOnly MaxAlterEnums As Int32 = Me.Values.Length

    Friend Function GetValue(ByVal Name As String) As Enums
        Return Me.Values.Where(Function(n) n.Name = Name).FirstOrDefault()
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Build(Of T As EBase)(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As Int32) As Enums
        Return New Enums(name, value, GetType(T))
    End Function

    Public Class Enums
        Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As Int32, ByVal type As Type)
            Me.Name = name
            Me.Value = value
            Me.Type = type
        End Sub
        Private _name As String
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return _name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As String)
                _name = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _value As Integer
        Public Property Value() As Integer
            Get
                Return _value
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
                _value = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _type As Type
        Public Property Type() As Type
            Get
                Return _type
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As Type)
                _type = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

End Class
```

Now your sample code works exactly as before:

```
    Dim Foo As EExample.Enums
    Foo = EExample.TwoB
    Debug.Print(Foo.Name)
```

And you are dealing with plain instances for you code implementation. The only `Shared` values are the five `Enums` and a private `_instance` variable.

You can now restrict on `EBase`.

Does this work for you?

---

Kumba pointed out that I didn't expose the `GetValue` function on the `EExample` class.

Just add this to `EExample`:

```
    Friend Shared Function GetValue(ByVal Name As String) As Enums
        Return _instance.GetValue(Name)
    End Function
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'm getting an `'Where' is not a member of 'System.Array'.` error when trying to test it.  Adding the `System.Data.Linq` reference doesn't resolve it, either.

Comment: Specifically in the `GetValue` method under the EBase class you implemented: `Return Me.Values.Where(Function(n) n.Name = Name).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Enigmativity: Got around the Linq issue (Never used it before), and now I'm trying to understand how, with your version, I can invoke `GetValue`.  In my version, It's shared, so I call the class directly.  In yours, it's not shared, so it needs an instance, but since the constructors are hidde from public consumption, there's no way to instance a new object and invoke `GetValue` from that context.  Unless I'm missing it.  You didn't give a whole lot of explanation of what you did differently.

Comment: FYI, just benchmarked your version against my version, and yours is a bit slower.  Here's the millisecond count of five consecutive runs at 100,000 invocations of a key function (which I can't reveal): 214ms, 207ms, 236ms, 199ms, & 203ms.  Five runs using the version that I built results in: 131ms, 167ms, 167ms, 160ms, & 157ms.

Comment: @Kumba - Yes, sorry, I used Linq, so I'm guessing you figured out that you need an `Imports System.Linq`.

Comment: @Kumba - I edited my answer to expose `GetValue` on the `EExample` class. My mistake not doing that first up.

Comment: @Kumba - When measuring these things make sure you discard any iterations that a garbage collection occurred as they can really affect performance measurement. The performance difference on average is 55.4ms. You would need 1.8 million invocations before the difference was a second. If you're making this many calls I'd suspect you have a problem with the calling code. There is little practical difference in performance as far as I can tell. Or is there something you need to explain further?

Comment: I haven't forgotten this, just tied up working on other areas of the program.  I will revisit this area in a few days (hopefully) and see if I can either find a workaround, or use this method.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I believe I am not going to need to use your provided example/solution because I've decided not to create a generic/abstract class that needs to restrict the generic type to one of my custom enum objects.  Thanks for the idea, however.  I am marking it as the correct answer because I believe it ultimately solve the problem if I chose to go down that path.  Good to keep around as a reference, too!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this sure sounds like it's getting deep quick.  Are you sure you need all that?

Wouldn't it be easier to associate the strings to enumeration values by creating a class, having the enums in the same file (or even nested in the same namespace, if you prefer), and then using a .ToFriendlyName() method to extract the string (that is, if it's designed for a human), and if you need to go the other way, you could create a constructor of the class that has a string argument and stores the associated enum.

Do you really need all of the arrays, inheritance and .GetValue overloads?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but from your initial description it sounds like the solution might be over-engineered by quite a bit.

Can you provide a bit more detail, especially regarding the "enum static classes" that you started from?  What's the root problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yeah, I suck at explaining things sometimes, so I just added code detailing what one of these enum classes looks like, just with dummy data inside.  The inheritance is really minimal, and the array lookups are fast.  I've benchmarked these things against what I was doing previously, and picked up a speed improvement of 300-400%, so the additional code per enum more than pays for itself.

Comment: For some reason, Stack's Markdown syntax highlighting dislikes the format of my code.  Probably a typo from copying it out of VB.NET.  I wish we had distinct <code> blocks.  This "indent four times" is annoying for large pieces of code.