# Fetch a shared member from a class when it is a generic type?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I have a bunch of classes that all contain a `Shared` `ReadOnly` Dictionary.  If I want to access that Dictionary when the class is a generic type (such as when I have a wrapper function that takes T as an interface that all of these classes implement), what's the way to do it?

Basic research suggests I want to do something like `GetType(T).GetMember("Dict")`, but that will return a `MemberInfo` type, and that cannot be cast to a Dictionary of my defined type(s).  For calling functions this way, one can use a delegate + `CreateDelegate` + `GetMethod`.  But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent `Create*`for GetMember stuff.  Or am I missing something?

If I plug the `GetMember` call into the immediate window, and then use a subscript as if it is an array, then the debug output says I am getting a Dictionary back.  But if I use that same approach in the actual function that I am trying to write, then I get an error about `System.Reflection.MemberInfo` cannot be converted to Dictionary(X, Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there.

`GetMember` returns an **array** of all the members with the name you pass (you can pass a string containing a wildcard `*` and get back multiple members). So in this case, you must index into the return value to get the actual `MemberInfo` you want.

Then in order to do anything with it, you'll need to cast it to the actual `-Info` type that it is, in this case a `FieldInfo`.

Once you've got a `FieldInfo`, you can call `GetValue` on it to get the actual value of the field. You'll need to pass `Nothing` to `GetValue`, since the field is shared, so the 'instance' you want to get this field's value for isn't an instance at all.

Finally you'll need to cast the return value of `GetValue` to your actual dictionary type, since it's typed as `Object`.

Then you can look in your dictionary.

This might seem long winded but only because I have spelled it out - if you are happy to go without error checking (which you should be, once it works), this will be a couple of lines at most.

<sub>The reason the Immediate Window 'just works' is because the debugger is doing all this for you behind the scenes. It's very helpful like that.</sub>

Comment: Okay, this works.  It's some ugly-looking code, but it works.  But it is also _slow_...  This is likely because of the use of Reflection, which is always a performance hog.  Is there a way to cache part of the lookup so that future calls while the program is running for that particular dictionary won't have to perform reflection again?  An idea similar to this is in another question that I [asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611890/faster-way-to-convert-from-a-string-to-generic-type-t-when-t-is-a-valuetype/4678430#4678430), which used a delegate to cache the function pointer.

Comment: PS, one idea I haven't explored yet is defining another stub function in each subclass within the base class (see my comment to @competent_tech on what these classes all are), slap an interface on that subclass, and have that class tie into the higher parent class to call the main code.  If I cannot cache the reflected lookup, or such caching is still slow, this may be an alternate route that still doesn't incur _too_ much function call overhead.  Really, the real purpose of this is to avoid multiple statements to `.ContainsKey` followed up by `.Item` within the Dictionary all over my project.

Comment: Okay, I just benchmarked the stub function idea, and it totally smokes my original implementation, even though at heart, it is adding _two_ function calls and still doing a `.ContainsKey` followed by `.Item` on the Dictionary.  In a tight timing loop of 100,000 times, it's about 200ms faster than straight up calling `.ContainsKey` and `.Item` independently.  I wonder if by moving those calls up to the containing subclass, I somehow activated a caching mechanism inside .NET that's giving me the performance boost?

Comment: If you do want to go back, one option would be to take the reflection hit *once* to build a `Dictionary<Type, Dictionary>` - then finding a particular type's dictionary is a lookup in that. Additionally I note that calling `TryGetValue` is far preferable to `ContainsKey`-then-`Item`, if you are often looking up keys that aren't in the dictionary.

Comment: Well, one performance boost I found was to use a `Dictionary(Of Int32, T)` versus `Dictionary(Of String, T)`, and simply populate the key via the string's `GetHashCode`.  That netted me a fair speedup.  I'll try `TryGetValue`, too, and see if that further speeds things up.  Still puzzled how the stub function approach sliced 200ms off, though.  It must've been some overhead of the object dereferencing when called from outside the Enums class.

Comment: `TryGetValue` shaved an additional 20ms off my tests, so I've adapted it.  Your answer wins, because even though the reflection approach is a performance killer, it might still offer someone some information down the road.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether or not your original request is possible, but the solution I would take would be to create an Interface to retrieve the property and have each of the classes implement this Interface to return the property. We use this mechanism extensively in our generic classes.

Comment: That's what I do for a lot of things, too.  In a few cases, I implement extensions that fetch a method by using delegates.  In this case, the dictionary is `Shared`, so I can't use an interface declaration on it (Why MS doesn't allow a type of shared/static set of interfaces for classes that only use shared/static members baffles me).

Comment: You actually can use an interface to provide this information, we do it all the time. You won't create the interface directly on the dictionary, you will use an instance member (property or function) that implements the interface, then use that to return the shared member. The only drawback is if you don't already have an instance of the class that implements the interface when you are retrieving the data through the interface, but it should be easy enough to create a throwaway instance in order to access the interface.

Comment: Except my classes here are never used as instances.  Everything in them is Shared, and only their shared members are ever referenced.  It's a hack to do better Enums, which I documented in another question I opened a while back [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4180742/482691).  They've evolved a lot since then, and I've even developed bitwise functions for a select few with very minimal performance penalties.  Hence why I cannot use interfaces as contracts for these classes (only the `Enums` sub-class defined in each base-level Enum class).